# C# jagged arrays

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

```
using System;
class TwoD
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[][,] a = new int[3][,];
        a[0] = new int[2, 2];
    //    a[1] = new int[3, 3];
        int i,j;
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                a[0][i,j] = i;//confused
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(a[0][i, j] + " "); 
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

This is the program and the output is

> 0
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> 1

But i am little bit confused about initialisation of jagges array where i have commented. Please tell me the initialisation of jagged two dimentional array and correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Add the line: `Console.WriteLine("Set:a[0]["+i+"," +j + "] to : " +  i);` after your comment to understand more

Comment: You only initialized a[0], a[1] and a[2] are null.  Since you don't use those elements, your program does not bomb with an NRE.  Might as well use new int[1][,] then, do sane things and you'll get sane outcomes.

Comment: What _exactly_ are you confused about?  You have an array of 2-d square arrays.  Think of it as stacking egg crates on top of each other, each of which could be a different size (2X3, 2X6, 3X6, etc.).  The initialization just puts a "new" egg crate on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about where you are confused but I guess only confusion is about mixture of [jagged array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) and [multidimensional array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx). i.e. a[][] is jagged array, the second dimension can have any (or no) length. You have to initialize each dimension in a separate look While multidimensional array have same length for each dimension and that's why you can pre-initialize the multidimensional array. Like a[2,5].

Below example will explain more about initialization of each kind of array and how you can write more dynamic code of your example.

```
//jagged array sample of initialization
int[][] jagged = new int[3][];

for (int i = 0; i < jagged.Length; i++)
    jagged[i] = new int[i + 4]; //each element of jagged array can have different length

//multidimensional array sample of initialization
int[,] multiD = new int[3, 4]; //that's it. 
//multiD.GetLength(0) is 3 and  multiD.GetLength(1) is 4

//Your example.

int[][,] a = new int[3][,];
a[0] = new int[2, 2];
a[1] = new int[3, 4];

int interationOrder = 0;

for (int jag = 0; jag < a.Length; jag++)
{
    //considering rank of multidimentional array is always 2 (Rank of [,] = 2, Rank of [,,] = 3)
    if (a[jag] == null)
        continue;

    for (int i = 0; i < a[jag].GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[jag].GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            a[jag][i, j] = interationOrder++;//no confusion :) this is corret.
        }
    }
}
```